# Как проверить что class = "X" и заменить X на Y?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка

Суть в том что мне нужно проверить если `class=like-r` где `id="colorlikreviews"` , то заменить `class=like-r` на `class=like-rs`, если нет то указать `class=like-r`

```
    if($("#colorlikreviews").className == 'like-r'){
        document.getElementById("colorlikreviews").className = 'like-rs';
    }else{
        document.getElementById("colorlikreviews").className = 'like-r';    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($("#colorlikreviews").hasClass("like-r")) {
  $("#colorlikreviews").removeClass("like-r");
  $("#colorlikreviews").addClass("like-rs");
} else {
  $("#colorlikreviews").addClass("like-r");
}
```

А ошибка, скорее всего, в `id` элемента: `"colorlikereviews"`.

*Update*

Ух-ты! Оказывается, `toggleClass` хитрее, чем я думал.

```js
function SwitchClass() {
    if ($("#colorlikreviews").hasClass("like-r")) {
      $("#colorlikreviews").toggleClass("like-r like-rs");
    } else {
      $("#colorlikreviews").addClass("like-r");
    }  
}
```

```css
.like-r {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  color:yellow;
}

.like-rs {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colorlikreviews">AAA</div>
<button onclick="SwitchClass()">Click</button>
```

Comment: спасибо, все понял

Answer (score 2):

> Как проверить что class = “X”

Проверять атрибут class на равенство - плохая идея.
class нужно рассматривать как список классов(с неопределённым порядком).
Для работы с этим списком у DOM элементов есть специальный объект [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

`Как проверить, что у элемента есть class X?`

Вот так:

```
if (el.classList(hasClass('X'))) {
  // ...
}
```

> и заменить X на Y?

Метода для подобной замены в classList нет.
Но мы всегда можем удалить один и добавить другой класс:

```
el.classList.remove('X');
el.classList.add('Y');
```

---

В примерах выше, `el` - DOM Element, субъект манипуляций.
Применительно к коду в вопросе это:

```
var el = document.getElementById("colorlikreviews");
```